# More widgets (js) in same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, widget

I created a js library that displays a dynamic widget, it works fine but when I want to display 2 widget on same page the problems begins. Indeed I will display only the second widget and I don't see the first

First widget

```
<script type="text/javascript">
wgppn_cat = 2;
wgppn_lines = 4;
wgppn_width = '400px';
wgppn_bgcolor = '#00C000';
</script>
<script src="wgppn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Second widget

```
<script type="text/javascript">
wgppn_cat = 5;
wgppn_lines = 4;
wgppn_width = '400px';
wgppn_bgcolor = '#FF0000';
</script>
<script src="wgppn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this is my js library wgppn.js

```
    var wgppn_lines; 
    var wgppn_width; 
    var wgppn_bgcolor;
    var wgppn_cat;

    wgppn_width = typeof wgppn_width == 'string' ? wgppn_width : '300px';
          wgppn_lines = typeof wgppn_lines == 'number' ? wgppn_lines : 3;
    wgppn_bgcolor = typeof wgppn_bgcolor == 'string' ? wgppn_bgcolor : '#003366';
    wgppn_cat = typeof wgppn_cat == 'number' ? wgppn_cat : 0;


    var script_tag = document.createElement('link');
          script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/css");
          script_tag.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
          script_tag.setAttribute("href","style.css");
          (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);


    var script_tag1 = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag1.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag1.setAttribute("src","jquery-latest.pack.js");    
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag1);

    var script_tag3 = document.createElement('div');
    script_tag3.setAttribute("id",'box');   
    (document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag3);

    var myRequest = CreateXmlHttpReq(myHandler);
    var url = window.location.href;
    myRequest.open("GET",url,true);
    myRequest.send(null);

    function CreateXmlHttpReq(handler) {
                var xmlhttp = null;
                try {
                     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                catch(e) {
                             try {
                                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                                 } 
                            catch(e) {
                                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                     }
                                 }
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handler;
              return xmlhttp;
    }

    function myHandler() {
        if (myRequest.readyState == 1) {
            var wHTML = ""; 
           wHTML += ('<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:180px;">');          
           wHTML += ('<img src="loader.gif" border="0" width="66" height="66"/>');
           wHTML += ('</div>');
           document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = wHTML;
        }       
        if (myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200) {
        loadcontent(wgppn_lines,wgppn_width,wgppn_bgcolor,wgppn_cat);

        }
    }


function loadcontent(wgppn_lines,wgppn_width,wgppn_bgcolor,wgppn_cat) {

    $(document).ready(function($) {

         var url = "data.asp?ln=" + wgppn_lines + "&cat=" + wgppn_cat
                    $.ajax({     
                            url: url,     
                            dataType: 'json', 
                            scriptCharset: 'utf-8' , 
                            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                            success: processJSON
                    });

            $('#box').css("width",wgppn_width);            

            });

    }

    function processJSON(result) { 

            var wHTML = ""; 
            wHTML += ('<div class="titolo_box" style="background-color:' + wgppn_bgcolor + '"></div>');
            wHTML += ('<ul>');  
            jQuery.each(result.news, function(i,val){

                wHTML += ('<li>');  
                wHTML += ('<div class="titolo_triplo">');
                wHTML += ('<img class="img3" src="' + val.pic + '" border="0" width="40" height="40"/>');
                wHTML += ('<a href="' + val.url + '" target="_blank" title="' + val.title + '">' + val.title + '</a>');           
                wHTML += ('</div>');    
                wHTML += ('<div class="strillo_triplo">');
                wHTML += ('<a href="' + val.url + '" target="_blank"  title="' + val.title + '">' + val.strillo + '</a>');            
                wHTML += ('</div>');                                      
                wHTML += ('</li>'); 
            }); 
            wHTML += ('</ul>');
            document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = wHTML;
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing some code? It should be built like a function or widget. And you dont have to call the plugin each time if you where to make it an function :)

Comment: the wgppn.js is executed for every widget in web page

Comment: In that case there are various problems with your code. First, you need to wrap it up in a function, so that you can create a new instance for each widget. You also need to re-structure the code so that you don't load the resources once for every instance of the widget - that is unnecessary.

Comment: can u show me an example please?

Comment: What is the widget supposed to do? As far as i can see it loads jquery, an CSS style, and set some properties. But it dosen't do anything with the properties, and i don't think you would want to add jquery or the css file multiple times. What is the goal of the widget?

Comment: You could start off by reading through [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript), which will point you in the right direction.

Comment: widget get some param in input call a script server side and with json display news dinamycally. when widget is one all is ok when are 2 no